# get data from multiple relations in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables **`pharmacies,categories,medicines`** and I am using laravel

the relations are like this

**pharmacy have many medicines and the medicine belongs to one category**

the `medicines` table have `pharmacy_id` and `category_id` columns + other columns

I want to show a pharmacy by id and it should return an object of pharmacy with categories, each category have object of medicines in this pharmacy. If there is no medicine in any category, then it should not be returned.

I think its a model relations issue

any idea could be useful

the category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function pharmacies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Pharmacy::class, 'pharmacy_category', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function medicines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Medicine::class);
    }
}
```

the pharmacy model

```
class Pharmacy extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'pharmacies';

    protected $appends = ['favourite'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'pharmacy_category','pharmacy_id','id');
    }

    public function getFavouriteAttribute()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (FavouritePharmacy::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('pharmacy_id', $this->id)->count() == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

the medicine model

```
class Medicine extends Model
{

    protected $appends = ['favourite'];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function getFavouriteAttribute()
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return 0;
        }
        return (FavouriteMedicine::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('medicine_id', $this->id)->count() == 1) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code?

Comment: Your question should demonstrate at least minimal effort to receive a response. In this case, it does not. Please show us your attempts to achieve this and any relevant errors.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I did not write the query yet, because I do not know how to start it

Comment: You should create `pharmacy`, `medicine`, `pharmacy_medicine` and `category`. Pharmacy belongs to many medicine, medicine belongs to many pharmacy. Medicine belongs to Category and Category has many Medicine. Medicine should have `category_id`. When getting pharmacies, you should eager load the other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display pharmacy info, categories with medicines, with these relationships I'd do this:

```
$pharmacy = Pharmacy::find($id);

$categoriesWithMedicines = Category::whereHas('medicines', function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('pharmacy_id', $id);
    })
    ->with(['medicines' => function($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('pharmacy_id', $id);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Then in a view, you'll have a pharmacy object and a list of categories with medicines which belong to the pharmacy:

```
@foreach ($categoriesWithMedicines as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
    @foreach ($category->medicines as $medicine)
        {{ $medicine->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I did approved it